# Who should the moderators be?

Tags: discussion, top-7, moderators

In weeks, this community will receive some provisional moderators to help get this site started prior to the elections at the end of the beta. Please read this: **[Moderators Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/)**.

**Please suggest some members of this community you feel would make excellent moderators *(self nominations are okay).***

Here are some basic guidelines:

- Each nomination should be a separate answer. Link the name to the user’s profile (parent and meta) so we can see their activity.
- The nominee should indicate their acceptance by editing the answer, adding that they accept the nomination. Optionally they can write something about themselves.
- Self nominations are okay, and even encouraged. Most sites have not had sufficient time for many users to stand out. Self nomination is simply a way to say, “I’m interested. Let my record speak for itself.” Links to other activities may be helpful: Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, blog posts reviewing or announcing the site, etc.

Here is what we are looking for in a Moderator...

We are seeking out members who are deeply engaged in the community’s development; members who:

- Have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation.
- Show an interest in their meta’s community-building activities.
- Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in A Theory of Moderation.

Bonus points for:

- Members with participation in both meta and the parent site (i.e. interest in both community building and expertise in the field).
- Area 51 participation, social network referrals, or blogging about the site.
- Members who have already shown an interest or ability to promote their community.

Comment: I'm not sure it isn't a little early for this question.  By the end of the private beta we should have a better idea who some of our big users are going to be.

Comment: @ICodeForCoffee: It's never too early to post one of the big 7 questions. The decision will be took independently of post date. Posting early we have more time to eval candidates.

Comment: While self-nominations are OK, I'd be more interested in people nominating someone else. A self nomination gives you a little information, from how someone describes themself; a nomination of someone else says that you've seen them in action, and from their actions, are willing to put your own reputation on the line by nominating someone else. That's a much bigger commitment, and thus statement about their qualities, to someone than an upvote is; no one knows who voted for whom, and people may upvote without having looked at someone else's track record. So, let's see some non-self nominations!

Comment: @Brian: Both has pros and cons. Have been nominated by pairs or by himself (or herself, although this seems to be another Marlboro land :-) ) can be used when you are analyzing the candidates. Know how a user see himself is a good thing **too**. To me both are equally valid.

Comment: @bigown They're definitely both equally valid. I'm just saying that I would prefer some non-self nominations; all we have now are self-nominations. We need to be thinking about who in the community would make a good moderator; looking around for someone else who stands out is a great way to do that.

Comment: @bigown And now I've put my money where my mouth is, and nominated you!

Comment: @BrianCampbell *cough* [link](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/42/who-should-the-moderators-be/154#154) *cough*

Comment: Out of curiosity, it looks like someone downvoted everybody's posts except for Gamecat and John Hadley... any particular reason for the mass downvote?

Comment: It was not me. I haven't recieved any vote yet. I probably remove my nomination if nobody is interested.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables I wouldn't worry about it; some people will have their reasons for downvoting or upvoting. It may not have been one person; it may have been a few people that each saw someone they disagree with. I would encourage people to share their concerns publicly, but it is fine to keep votes secret if you want to.

Comment: Locking this as I believe the temporary moderators have been chosen.

Comment: @Pat Ludwig -- unlocked to ask this -- yes, temporary moderators have been chosen, but isn't this question for picking permanent moderators?  If so, this shouldn't be locked.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables - moderators will not be chosen again until the site leaves beta (2-3 months).  I suggest that any data gathered now for that contingency will be stale when it is needed.  I think we should start fresh nearer to that time.

Comment: @Pat Ludwig - that's fine, I'll defer to you on this one.

Answer (score 11):

I nominate [Brian Campbell](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/privileges) ([meta](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/users/112/brian-campbell)) because of his obvious enthusiasm, excellent meta posts, and [experience with the SO engine](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/users/112?tab=accounts).

Brian, if you accept, please give us some more information about yourself and your experience.

**I accept** the nomination to be a moderator pro tempore. I cannot commit at this time to being a moderator beyond the beta period, but I am willing to accept the duties of a moderator until the official election, and at that time I may decide to run again, but I may step down.

I have extensive experience with the StackExchange platform. I have been a contributor at StackOverflow for over a year and a half, and am among the top 250 users in reputation there. I am familiar with all of the moderator tools available to those without a ♦ next to their name; I am relatively frequently involved in discussions about whether to close or make a question CW. I have also been involved somewhat at [meta.so](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/69755/brian-campbell), to try and make the platform as a whole better.

As mentioned, I've participated pretty heavily in boardgames.se, as well as meta, to try and definite what this site should be about. I would love to see this site succeed, as I find it one of the best formats for asking and answering questions on any given topic.

I have [participated in BoardGameGeek in the past](http://boardgamegeek.com/user/lambda), though it's been a few years since I've been active there. I also host and administer the [Looney Labs Fan Wiki](http://rabbits.continuation.org/wiki/Main_Page) and [Icehouse Games Wiki](http://rabbits.continuation.org/wiki/Main_Page).

As far as games go, I like a wide range, but tend to lean towards abstracts, Euros, and game systems like playing cards and Icehouse, while I also play a lot of word games and party games. The game I play most seriously is [Go](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_(game)), though I'm not all that good (double digit kyu, for those who are familiar with the game). I also do medieval recreation in the [SCA](http://www.sca.org/), and so I've learned and teach a good number of medieval board and card games.

In my professional life, I'm a programmer, as you might guess from my StackOverflow reputation. My education is in computer science, though I studied math and linguistics fairly extensively as well. Other hobbies of mine include juggling and archery, and I commute to work by bicycle.

And finally, my approach to moderation. As a moderator, I would take the consensus of the community very seriously. If there is a community consensus on an issue, such as what is on and off topic, then that is what I will try to uphold. I am aware that the ♦ next to your name will make people take what you say and do more seriously, and so I would be very careful to be even-handed, and not take action unless there is a clear community consensus, or there is an emergency and no consensus immediately apparent. For instance, I would be very reluctant to unilaterally close a question, unless it was very clearly inappropriate and needed immediate attention.

That said, part of the job of a moderator is to help lead the community. In cases in which consensus is not readily apparent, the moderator can be a tie-breaking voice, speaking with more authority. Our discussions are not votes; I may choose the slightly less popular choice, if I believe that it is more consistent with the mission of the community or more likely to lead the community to a better place. I will not act against a clear consensus, but I will make decisions when no consensus can be reached and no further discussion is likely to be productive.

Please let me know if you have any questions about me or my approach to moderation. Thank you for the nomination!

Comment: Good call, I support this nomination!

Comment: Thanks for the nomination! I'm thinking about it; I will get back to you in a few days. I don't yet have enough rep on meta to edit the post; perhaps you can make it CW like I did with Bigown's nomination so I can edit it?

Comment: @BrianCampbell Done.

Comment: Having just read Brian's excellent 'Anyone know more 'social' games like 'Werewolves"' answer +1 for leading by example.

Comment: He has my total support! No one deserves more.

Comment: Just to add to the praise: I think Brian's answers are the most interesting ones on the site, both parent and meta. I strongly support his nomination.

Answer (score 3):

I nominate [bigown](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/users/67) ([meta](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/users/67/bigown)). He is in the top 10 users in rep so far, demonstrating that he's contributing actively. He has participated quite a lot in meta, and has shown an even-handed approach to many of the topics. He is [already a moderator](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/389/bigown) at programmers.se, where he contributes heavily and actively, demonstrating that he has at least some experience with moderating this sort of community.

bigown, do you accept this nomination? If so, please edit it to add some more information to this nomination about yourself, your approach to moderation, and the like.

Comment: If @bigown thinks he can handle two sites I'm all for it.

Comment: My only concern is that he has 9 questions open, a number of them with valid answers, and a 0% acceptance rate.  Bigown is certainly contributing actively, but I think a few of the questions have valid answers worth accepting.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables some of us like to leave questions open a few days, to give others a chance to compete for that accepted bonus.

Comment: @C. Ross - Fair enough, I guess I just have a different way of using the site, and I accept that.  Last you'll hear about it from me.

Comment: Sorry, I had a lot of work these days. First I wanna thank to Brian. I can't say anything now. If my nomination has support I will think seriously about it. Thanks to C. Ross and up voters. @LittleBobbyTables: For me accept any answer before public beta doesn't make any sense. This is just my personal opinion. Anyway I am waiting to more answers from new users. I didn't accept by negligence, I choose that way.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to nominate [Pat Ludwig](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/users/40/pat-ludwig)/[meta](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/users/40/pat-ludwig). Not just because he has the highest reputation score currently, but because of the activity, detail of answers and commitment to the site.

Well, 2 negative votes already so this may be wasted effort, but nothing ventured, nothing gained right? :)

**I accept** this nomination.

I'll state up front that my qualifications in terms of stackexchange/stackoverflow experience are slight.  I'm currently the #2 rep'd user of rpg.stackexchange.com (3500 rep), plus #1 here.  While I haven't actively participated in previous SE sites, I have been reading [Joel Spolsky's blog](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/) for many years and I did witness the founding of stackoverflow.com.  It seemed a great idea, but in my work I didn't have a pressing need for the answers offered there.  Periodically I checked back in and discovered the [RPG SE](http://rpg.stackexchange.com) in August.  I jumped in with both feet and committed here as well.

I've been playing games all of my life.  I think first "real" boardgame was Risk, but I progressed into various SPI games, D&D, Star Fleet Battles, Battletech.  Then I was introduced to Civilization.  Wow, that was an eye-opener!  My favorite 3 games of all time still are:

- [Advanced Civilization](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgameexpansion/177/advanced-civilization)
- [Empires in Arms](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/254/empires-in-arms)
- [Age of Renaissance](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/26/age-of-renaissance)

I've been deeply involved in many facets of the game industry over the years.

- Owner of [Boldo's Armory](http://boldo.com) game store (We've been in business since 1995, store opened in 1997, I've been a mostly silent partner since 2000)
- Competitive chess player for over 10 years
- Taught chess, ran tournaments (including one for nearly 200 kids)
- Ran dozens if not hundreds of games and demos at conventions
- Majored in Bridge at college (this is not what I told my parents!)
- Leader of the [Austin BoardGame Group](http://games.groups.yahoo.com/group/austinboardgamers/) for 2 years

I have read, and agree to the [Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).  Almost all of the time, the community will be able to self-moderate this site and do it well.  There will be a few occasions when a moderator will need to step in and quickly address a situation.  I stand ready to take action when appropriate.

If there are any questions I can answer, please let me know.

--Pat

Comment: I accept this nomination.  @Codemwnci, could you CW this answer so that I may edit it and state my credentials for the record?  Thanks!

Comment: Done. Edit away.

Comment: It's a good nomination.

Answer (score 2):

I'll go ahead and throw my hat into the ring as well.  I'm interested in moderation because I like to help make sure that sites I'm very interested in can run as smoothly as possible, and think this would be a great learning experience as well.

While I'm relatively new to the StackExchange sites (been here just over five months now), the great attitudes of everyone here, plus the ability to help people, is what made me stay.

I contribute to both ([StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/334849/littlebobbytables) as well as the [Board Game beta](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/users/6/littlebobbytables), and while I don't have very high rep on SO, I feel it's because I answer in lower-traffic areas.  I visit both sites every day.

I have moderated a community in LiveJournal in the past (which can be like herding cats some times), was a moderator for a MUD waaaaaay back in the day, and actually find moderating to be fascinating and rewarding.

I have been playing board games for as long as I can remember -- my wife and I don't have cable TV, and instead opt to play board games (and video games to some extent) as entertainment.  I *love* Puerto Rico and Power Grid, and also play Settlers of Catan, Carcassonne, Chez Geek, Munchkin and Scrabble with regularity.  I've picked up Chaos in the Old World and Horus Heresey, and will get to play them some day.  I used to play tabletop games as well, but have switched over to board games for their accessiblity.

I would describe my moderation style as "slow-to-provoke, quick-to-respond".  In the case of the poker spamming yesterday, I tried commenting on the user's questions to no avail.  If I had been a moderator, as soon as the Spam and Moderation Required warnings came in, I would have most likely suspended them as well due to spamming and ignoring requests to stop.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, we obviously need moderators, so I'll start by nominating [myself](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/users/31/michiel-de-mare). I love boardgames, play them a lot, and have been active here since the beta of stackoverflow. I'd love to help making this community a success. I'm not a deletionist but I hate spam and badly written questions.

That said, there are many fine people here who'd also make great moderators.

Comment: How you would deal with bad written questions?

Comment: Have you ever modded another site?  Any relevant experience?

Comment: @bigown Edit titles, prod repeat offenders to be clearer and close hopeless questions.

Comment: @C.Ross None whatsoever :) But how hard can it be?

Comment: @Michiel Pushing the buttons is easy.  Knowing *when* to push the buttons is **hard**.  I'm not saying you're not qualified, just seeing if there was anything you left out.

Comment: If you're opinion is "how hard can it be" then you probably don't really understand the post very well. :)

Answer (score 0):

And another shameless self nomination.

As a 2 year+, 20k+ member of SO, I have some experience with the site mechanics including the mod tools. And I'm mostly aware of the (un)written rules on site behaviour. Besides I am a game addict. (hence my nickname which I carry for more than 5 years now).

I have been a moderator/administrator on some internet fora and a channel operator on an IRC channel. Experience with trolls and ill behaved users. The later are hard to cope with because you like to teach them how to behave but sometime they and the community do not fit together.

My primary goal is to be part of a great community for (board and card game lovers). The task of a moderator is to be like the oil in the machine. You don't see it often, its used to keep things going, and if you mess with it you get dirty ;-).  And don't forget, you have to replace it when its no longer functional.

On the personal level. We have recently moved from the (small)city to a vilage called Nootdorp in the Netherlands (just 5 km east of Den Hague where I work as a software developer). I have a family, two sons. The oldest is becomming a game addict too which proves the investment finally pays of ;-).
I collect games for 20 years now. We like to play games if we have time and energy but that is not to often. And of course I'm a dungeon master for 20 years now (I know OT, but experience can be relevant).

If you have any questions, don't hesitate to ask. I will check the site several times a day.

Comment: Why the downvote?  If somebody thinks I'm not qualyfied, fine but please tell me why.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to nominate myself, as the meta area of this site has engaged me more than any other SE site. My reputation in both sites hopefully supports this.

I'm a grizzled [freelance web developer](http://uk.linkedin.com/in/jonhadley) of 10+ years experience, as such I've been involved in (and built) many web forums and moderated many of the arguments and personality clashes that occur within them. My first experience of moderation was as an #ircnewbies channel operator, back when my Windows 3.1 machine didn't have enough oomph for Mosaic!

I am an active user on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/161525/jon-hadley) and also (most usefully in relation to this site), [gaming.stackexchange.com](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/371/jon-hadley). I've also submitted and contributed to a number of other beta sites on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/8878/jon-hadley).

Stack Exchange is, in my opinion, the best Q&A system to appear in the last decade.

I use my full, real name on all sites and I'm happy to carry my professional reputation with me as a result.

Board/Card game wise I am a big fan of Diplomacy, but can also be found playing Chess, Poker, Scrabble and more recently, Carcassonne.

I'm UK based and so able to care for the site when the US moderators are asleep.

I am a married father of a 2 year old son, so I can display patience and tact in the face of provocation and immaturity, regardless of my energy levels ;)

Finally, above all else I'd like to try to keep to the central tenant of [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/):

> We intended Stack Overflow and Server Fault to be mostly self-regulating....
>
> Moderators are human exception
>   handlers, there to deal with those
>   (hopefully rare) exceptional
>   conditions that should not normally
>   happen...

Comment: Your accounts on SO and gaming.se don't seemed to be linked to this one. That's how I originally tried to check out where else you were active. Not a problem, just something I thought I'd point out. I like your emphasis on moderators being the exception rather than the rule. I'm concerned about the fact that you don't have enough rep on any trilogy site to even have privileges to edit other people questions and answers, let alone moderation tools. That indicates a bit of a lack of experience with the communities and tools at hand.

Comment: @Brian I think my lack of high rep on *one* SO site is probably due to spreading myself rather thinly across them *all* - as I say, BG has engaged me more than any other, hence why I wish to become more involved. (I oticed the odd linking too (it's the same OpenID), had a warning e-mail from the Area51 system pointing it out too. Looking into it. )

Comment: Good answer, thanks for responding.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question discouraged self-nominations, but I'm the only one who knows me so - I'm throwing my hat in the ring.

I am active here (top 5 rep) and on rpg.stackexchange.com. I've only been boardgaming for about 4 years, but I've played more games than anyone else I know personally.

I really enjoy this SE and would love the opportunity to take on a moderation role - especially in a *pro tempore* capacity, because I have no moderation experience excepting that for my own, **much** smaller sites.

I game with a broad variety of people, including my wife, my son (14), his friends, "couple" friends, and more stereotypical "gamers".

I am the rules authority in my group - called upon for fairness in rulings as well as quick lookups in large manual.

Thanks for welcoming me to this SE, and I hope I'm able to participate as a moderator.